# Magento 1 Update/append product categories in database

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, category, query

I want mysql query for append or add new category ID to exsting product categories.

Comment: Please share so far what you have tried ?

Comment: I have not tried anything which i will share with you..

Comment: You should Try some thing and then if you are facing issue then you may ask for help in community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `test.php` file at magento root and add below code in this file  after run in browser

```
<?php 
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $categoryId = 3;
  $productId  = 5;
  $position   = 3; // Any int number 
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
  $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
  $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, null, null);
  $positions[$productId] = $position; //It is user for single product id   

  /**
   * if your passed multiple product ids then used 
  $productIds = array(1,2,35,10);
  $position = 3;
  foreach($productIds as $productId) {
      $positions[$productId] = $position;
      $position++;
  }
  */

  $category->setPostedProducts($positions);
  try {
      $category->save();
  } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

**Note:** Please put your category & product id in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Sql query add the new category to existing products..

```
INSERT INTO
catalog_category_product(category_id, product_id,position ) 
VALUES('Your New category ID','Your Product ID','Position');
```